# Implementing computational graph and autograd for tensor and matrix

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a very simple deep learning framework like PyTorch in order to get a better understanding of computational graphs and automatic differentiation. I implemented an automatic differentiator for scalar values inspired by [this](https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd) and then was trying to implement a tensor automatic differentiator that you can see in my code below.

```
import numpy as np
class Tensor:
    def __init__(self,data,_children=()):
        self.data=data
        self.grad=np.zeros_like(self.data)
        self._prev=set(_children)
        self._backward=lambda :0
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tensor of shape {self.data.shape} with grad {self.grad}"

    def dag(self):
        topo=[]
        visited=set()
        def build_topo(v):
            visited.add(v)
            for i in v._prev:
                if(i not in visited):
                    build_topo(i)
                else:
                    pass
            topo.append(v)

        build_topo(self)
        topo.reverse()
        return topo
        
    def backward(self):
        topo=self.dag()
        self.grad=np.ones_like(self.data)
        for v in topo:
            v._backward()

    @staticmethod
    def sum(self,other):
        _tensor=Tensor(self.data+other.data,(self,other))
        def _back():
            self.grad=_tensor.grad
            other.grad=_tensor.grad
        _tensor._backward=_back
        return _tensor

    @staticmethod
    def dot(self,other):
        assert self.data.shape[1]==other.data.shape[0],  \
            f"can't multiply two Tensor with shape {self.data.shape} and {other.data.shape}"
        _tensor=Tensor(np.dot(self.data,other.data),(self,other))
        def _back():
            self.grad=(_tensor.grad*other.data.T)
            other.grad=(_tensor.grad*self.data)
        _tensor._backward=_back
        return _tensor
```

My question is how am I suppose to implement an automatic differentiator for when we have a matrix of input data where each input is a column vector of the matrix (like what we do in a neural network for training)?

I would appreciate it if you give me some study material or sample code so I can implement PyTorch like autograd for matrix input or tensors.

Comment: the original micrograd simply used the rules of differentiation of sums and products of values to construct the synthesized grad and also keep track of it. So for multi-dimensional entities one simply can do the analog of rules of differentitaion for vectors and matrices, ... Else one can simply construct tensors from Values and keep track of those meticulously

Comment: yes, does pytorch use same idea? Cuz i don't think it is an efficient implementation. if vector itself does't construct of values object one can use numpy to do operation. my question is that how can i implement pytorch like autograd?Thanks.

Comment: use the differentiation rules for vectors,matrices, tensors, instead of scalar values that's all, but it is not that simple as it is for scalar values, eg you have to create multidimensional gradients and keep track of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comments an answer.

Effectively `micrograd` engine, uses the reverse mode of automatic differentiation (stored in the `backward` method) in order to calculate the derivatives as they pass through the various layers starting from the final output (**reverse mode**). This is needed for training NNs.

To generalise this to vector/matrix entities one can follow one of 2 approaches:

1. Construct matrices from scalar `Value`s, and keep using `micrograd`.
2. Generalise the reverse mode differentiation rules to use matrices/tensors.

Both can be used and which is most efficient depends on various factors along with ease of implementation.

To follow the 2nd approach (and make sth like `PyTorch`), one has to generalise the gradients for scalars to gradients of matrices and the reverse mode differentiation rules of scalars to matrices.

For example (reference 3 below):

Assuming a binary operator $C = f(A, B)$ that takes 2 matrices $A, B$ and produces a 3rd matrix $C$. The reverse mode automatic differentiation rule is:

1. $C = f(A, B) = A+B$, reverse mode grad: $\operatorname{grad}A=\operatorname{grad}C, \operatorname{grad}B=\operatorname{grad}C$
2. $C = f(A, B) = A \cdot B$, reverse mode grad: $\operatorname{grad}A=\operatorname{grad}C \cdot B^T, \operatorname{grad}B=A^T \cdot \operatorname{grad}C$
3. $C = f(A) = A^T$, reverse mode grad: $\operatorname{grad}A=\operatorname{grad}C^T$
4. $C = f(A) = A^{-1}$, reverse mode grad: $\operatorname{grad}A=-C^T \cdot \operatorname{grad}C \cdot C^T$
5. and so on.. (see reference)

So that is the way to generalise the operations to take account of matrix entities (these rules would be put in the respective `backward` method). **Note:** for scalar values (ie degenerate matrices of shape 1 x 1) the above rules degenerate to the `micrograd` (reverse differentiation) rules for scalar `Value`s.

References:

1. [Matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)
2. [Vector, Matrix, and Tensor Derivatives](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf)
3. [An extended collection of matrix derivative results for forward and reverse mode algorithmic differentiation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-extended-collection-of-matrix-derivative-results-Giles/c74c5e11ed05246c12165ce7e4b6222bd32d68dc)
4. [Automatic Differentiation for Matrices (Differentiable Programming)](https://www.deep-teaching.org/notebooks/differentiable-programming/exercise-automatic-differentiation-matrix)